# Can I make "comment-region" comment empty lines?

Tags: comment

In `LaTeX` code I can have:

```latex
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
\begin{comment}
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
\end{comment}
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

If I use `comment-region` (in a script) to comment the `comment` environment in la `LaTeX` code i obtain:

```latex
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
%% \begin{comment}
%% adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

%% Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
%% \end{comment}
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

This is not good because `LaTeX` interpret the empty line(s) (outside of `comment` environment) as a paragraph break.

My question is: Can I make `comment-region` comment empty lines?

I tried customizing (let-bind) the  `comment-syle`  variable but all the options I've seen do not comment empty lines.

An alternative could be a "built-in" (otherwise I already know how to make this funcion by myself) function that let me append a string on every line of a region (not a triangle). Remember, I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Customize option `comment-empty-lines`.

> **`comment-empty-lines`** is a variable defined in `newcomment.el`.
>
> Documentation:
>   If `nil`, `comment-region` does not comment out empty lines.
>   If `t`, it always comments out empty lines.
>   If `eol` it only comments out empty lines if comments are
>   terminated by the end of line (i.e. `comment-end` is empty).